# Find system information

Tags: java, system

I'd like to find out things like:

- What hardware the computer has using java(network card).
- If there was an USB flash drive introduced and maybe what the flash drive had(file names,directories,size).
- What IP addresses have been accessed, or sites.

How to get that information?

Comment: 1) SpyWare alert! 2) However you do this, it won't be in Java.  Wrong language (fortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sigar API provides a portable interface for gathering system information such as:

System memory, swap, cpu, load average, uptime, logins
Per-process memory, cpu, credential info, state, arguments, environment, open files
File system detection and metrics
Network interface detection, configuration info and metrics
TCP and UDP connection tables
Network route table
This information is available in most operating systems, but each OS has their own way(s) providing it.
SIGAR provides developers with one API to access this information regardless of the underlying platform.
The core API is implemented in pure C with bindings currently implemented for Java, Perl, Ruby, Python, Erlang, PHP and C#.

Check their homepage:

https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do that is by JNI. The env-variables wont tell you those details. Write a little program in C / C++ and Access the functions by JNI

by the way: METALLICA!!!

Comment: *"by the way: METALLICA!!!"*  Whatever that is supposed to mean, it seems inappropriate for an answer.  And stop SHOUTING.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Come on, JNI is capslocked, too. Dont be like that!

Comment: *"Come on, JNI is capslocked, too"*  JNI is an abbreviation.  *"Dont be like that!"*  Don't be so lazy!  Use upper case only when appropriate.